# How to change classnames of list elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component, that a list of items.

```
render() {
    const { clickHandler } = this.props;
return (
    <section className="container birds-list">
        <ul className="birds-list__list">
            {this.props.list.map(({name, id}) => (
                <li key={id} className="birds-list__item">
                    <div className="shape shape-default"></div>
                    <div onClick={clickHandler} className="birds-list__item-name">{name}</div>
                </li>
            )
            )}
        </ul>
    </section>
```

In clickHandler function I change background color of div with shape class name like `e.target.previousSibling.classList.add('shape-complete');`

But when I want to rerender my component with new names, I want to change all div elements with default class names with 'shape shape-default' instead of it I have div elements with classes, that I added ('shape shape-default shape-complete')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mutated the DOM outside of React. You should instead control your classnames within "Reactland". A method for achieving this is to maintain a map or some data structure in state of "selected" or "clicked" elements to which a classname is applied (think similar to a checkbox being checked).

```
state = {
  clicked: {},
};

const clickHandler = id => this.setState(prevState => {
  const newClicked = {...prevState.clicked};
  newClicked[id] = !newClicked[id];
  return newClicked;
});

render() {
  ...
  this.props.list.map(({name, id}) => {
    const classNames = ['shape shape-default'];
    if (this.state.checked[id] classNames.push('shape-complete');

    return (
      <li key={id} className="birds-list__item">
        <div className={classNames.join(' ')}></div>
        <div onClick={clickHandler} className="birds-list__item-name">{name}</div>
      </li>
    )
  })
  ...
```

Using the `classnames` npm package simplifies this a bit

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
...

state = {
  clicked: {},
};

const clickHandler = id => this.setState(prevState => {
  const newClicked = {...prevState.clicked};
  newClicked[id] = !newClicked[id];
  return newClicked;
});

render() {
  ...
  this.props.list.map(({name, id}) => {
    const classnames = classNames(
      'shape',
      'shape-default',
      {
        'shape-complete': this.state.checked[id],
      },
    );

    return (
      <li key={id} className="birds-list__item">
        <div className={classnames}></div>
        <div onClick={clickHandler} className="birds-list__item-name">{name}</div>
      </li>
    )
  })
  ...
```